# Значение ссылочной переменной зануляется

Tags: c#

Мне необходимо использовать переменные из класса Input в классе алгоритм, но при обращении к ним, они равны нулю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace ОСАПР
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inp = new Input();
            inp.INPUT();
            Console.WriteLine("n из мейна " + inp.n);
            Console.WriteLine("m из мейна " + inp.m);
            Algorithm Al = new Algorithm();
            Al.ALG();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        class Input
        {
            public int alpha { get; set; }
            public int beta { get; set; }
            public int n { get; set; }
            public int m { get; set; }
            public int[,] Matrix { get; set; }
            public void INPUT()
            {
                    StreamReader f = new StreamReader(@" C:\Users\IIsha\source\repos\ОСАПР\Данные.txt");
                    alpha = Convert.ToInt32(f.ReadLine());
                    beta = Convert.ToInt32(f.ReadLine());
                    n = Convert.ToInt32(f.ReadLine());//строки
                    m = Convert.ToInt32(f.ReadLine());//столбики
                    string[] array = new string[n];//записываем строки из txt
                    int[] arr = new int[n];//записываем числа
                    Matrix = new int[n, m];
                    while (!f.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string ss = f.ReadLine();
                        array = ss.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        {
                            int.TryParse(array[i], out arr[i]);
                        }
                        Matrix[arr[0] - 1, arr[1] - n - 1] = arr[2];
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Матрица расстояний:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//матрица
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Matrix[i, j]);
                            Console.Write(" ");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                f.Close(); 
                Console.WriteLine("n из инпута " + n);
            }
        }
        class Graph 
        {
        }

        class Algorithm
        {
            public int[,] Distances { get; set; }//матрица вероятностей перехода
            public int[,] Verification_matrix { get; set; }//матрица проверки были ли выбрана вершина ранее
            public double dist { get; set; }//расстояние между вершинами
            public void ALG()
            {
                var INP = new Input();
                Console.WriteLine("n из аглоритма " + INP.n);
                Console.WriteLine("m из аглоритма " + INP.m);
                Distances =new int[INP.n, INP.m];
                Verification_matrix = new int[INP.n, INP.m];
                int prob_str=0;//сумма вероятностей строки
                for (int i = 0; i < INP.n; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("хочу увидеть это сообщение!!1");
                    for (int j = 0; j < INP.m; j++)
                    {
                        prob_str = prob_str + 1/ INP.Matrix[i, j];
                        Console.WriteLine(prob_str = prob_str + 1 / INP.Matrix[i, j]);
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < INP.m; j++)
                    {
                        //dist = (1 / INP.Matrix[i, j])^INP.beta/();
                    }
                    prob_str = 0;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в классе `Algorithm` переменная `INP` локальна, так как объявляется в функции. Сделайте её свойством и обращайтесь к нему

Comment: @iKuzmychov Спасибо, переставил, но проблема не решилась. В `Algorithm` переменная `INP` объявляется в свойствах, но остальные переменные все еще равны 0

Comment: не могу вам помочь, пока не покажите обновлённый код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В мейне вы после создания класса вызываете метод, загружающий данные

```
var inp = new Input();
inp.INPUT();
```

А в алгоритме не вызываете

```
var INP = new Input();
```

`new` создает новый экземпляр класса, его пустую копию. Это ООП.

Решить можно двумя способами:

1. Вызвать `inp.INPUT();` в алгоритме
2. Передать уже созданный `Input` в алгоритм (на мой взгляд более правильно)

Можно передать в метод:

```
public void ALG(Input input)
{
    Console.WriteLine("n из аглоритма " + input.n);
    Console.WriteLine("m из аглоритма " + input.m);
    // остальной код...
}
```

И вызвать так

```
Algorithm Al = new Algorithm();
Al.ALG(inp);
```

Можно передать в конструктор:

```
private Input input;

public Algorithm(Input inp)
{
    input = inp;
}

public void ALG()
{
    Console.WriteLine("n из аглоритма " + input.n);
    Console.WriteLine("m из аглоритма " + input.m);
    // остальной код...
}
```

И вызывать вот так

```
Algorithm Al = new Algorithm(inp);
Al.ALG();
```

---

Совет, не делайте вложенных типов. У вас такая структура

```
class
{
    class { }
    class { }
}
```

А надо вот так

```
class { }
class { }
class { }
```

Меньше путаться будете

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь и советы, исправлю код и запомню на будущее

Comment: @ТимурШакиров почитайте еще где-нибудь о том, как правильно называть переменные, классы, методы т.д. в C#, а то у вас в этой области тоже каша.